# Convert pp::Var array in chrome native client to a C integer array

Tags: c, arrays, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I am working on a google chrome extension wherein I am receiving an array of integers from the extension by `pp::Var shared = dict_message.Get("shared_list");`. Now I need to pass on this array to a C function, hence need to get the elements into `int*`. How do I go about doing that ?

Comment: Your question would be better if you were to find some documents to read, and try something, coming back if you have problems with what you tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure the `pp::Var` is really an array.

```
if (shared.is_array()) {
```

Then, use the interfaces provided by class `pp::VarArray`.

```
    pp::VarArray array(shared);
    int * carray = new int[array.GetLength()];
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < array.GetLength(); ++i) {
        pp::Var oneElem(array.Get(i));
        assert(oneElem.is_number());
        carray[i] = oneElem.AsInt();
    }
    // carray is ready to use
    delete [] carray;
}
```

Comment: Is it the same code for C++? I know C++ can work with C but maybe it will be shorter for C++. I'm having the same problem in my C++ code.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused because of the title of this question.